# Is it safe to instantiate a form and call ShowDialog from within BeginInvoke?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it safe to instantiate a form and call ShowDialog from within BeginInvoke?

BeginInvoke run the task on the same thread on which the control had been created.
So as far as i know should be ok ...

I am just asking if such creation may lead to some hangs, deadlocks, etc..

Comment: More exactly: from a function called by BeginInvoke. Yes, it is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ambiguous, sure sounds like you instantiate the form first and then call BeginInvoke().  No, that's **not** okay.  It will *look* like it will work since ShowDialog() pumps a message loop.  But you'll have a raft of very nasty glitches.  The mild stuff is the window not being modal to the other windows in the app.   And not having a Z-order relationship with the other windows in your app which can cause it to easily disappear behind another window.  Nastier stuff is that the thread probably isn't an STA thread, things like drag + drop, the clipboard and the shell dialogs will not work.  The *really* nasty stuff is getting the SystemEvents class to start firing events on the wrong thread, that problem lasts past the dialog and crashes or hangs your app at unpredictable times later.

Only ever create a form instance on the UI thread.  Which means that you must use the BeginInvoke() method of **another** instance of a form, one that was created earlier.  If you are desperate to find one then Application.OpenForms[0] may give you one.

Comment: No no, I am instantiating the form in BeginInvoke inside, and call ShowDialog inside as well. BeginInvoke is executed from main UI control, so in that scenerio should be ok? :)

Comment: Yes, that's okay, as I described.

Answer (score -1):

Is it safe to call ShowDialog inside BeginInvoke, it would be a problem if you would call ShowDialog from a background thread.

Comment: Unless you've typo'd, your first sentence is merely a repeat of the question? and the second is an answer to a question that wasn't asked